# C++ Builder: Cannot bind, address already in use

Tags: android, sockets, c++builder, rad-studio

I have an application running on Android, it uses Bluetooth in some tabs (using sockets, after I include it on my project, I get the warning), and when I run (only) debugging it shows me a warning: `Cannot bind, address already in use.`

The situation is:

- If I run not debugging, it shows no warning.
- If I include a parameter on `Project/Options/Debugger/Parameters` (e.g: `-debugport=54321`) and I run using debug, it execute with no warnings.

It seems to be the port that I'm using to debug is busy, but I can't find a way to "set another port" or "if port `n` is busy, go to another", because I don't want to put parameters (the `debugport`) on my settings.

Maybe some code to modify the state of the ports of IDE, or even in adb.exe

**EDIT**: My program is running normally, I just want to hide this warning (not forever, but a solution to this occasion).

**EDIT 2**: When I run for the first time (restarting PC and Android phone) I get no errors (in this case it will be the first time that it's using this port), I don't know if some function/method to free the port that the application was using will resolve the problem.

For some code to have in mind of my project: The whole process of sockets and connection is based in the sample that Embarcadero offers, I'm using "Classic Bluetooth Basic app" (it includes `FSocket->Free();` and    `FServerSocket->Free();` that seems to free the socket and resolve problem, but no).

How can I deal with it?

Answer (score -2):

You need to reconnect your usb chord from your device. It will work!!!